# Opening a YouTube video in lightbox for different youtube links

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, lightbox

I am trying to open the YouTube video for the multiple links with single java script. But the javascript is been written only for the single link. How to link it to other youtube link.
If I click on the particular image the lightbox must open and the video must play. In this code only the 1st link will get the lightbox where a the 2nd link will be redirected to youtube page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        $("#yt").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                    'padding'        : 0,
                    'autoScale'      : false,
                    'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                    'title'          : this.title,
                    'width'          : 680,
                    'height'         : 495,
                    'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                    'type'           : 'swf',
                    'swf'            : {
                        'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                        'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
    $('#foo').bind('click', function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        });
        $('#foo').trigger('click');
</script>
```

```
    <h1>fancybox example</h1>
 <p><a id="yt"title=""href="http://www.youtube.com/watchv=h3GEQIbcfwA&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">sadf</a></p>  <p><a id="yt" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com/watchv=pAJxACKSdMM;autoplay=1">adfa</a></p>
```

How to make the the above java script to work for both the hyperlink. Please some one help to solve this issue.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean how do you code it so that when clicking on *either* of the links open both videos?

Comment: more specifically <img src="a1.gif"  /><a id="yt" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3GEQIbcfwA"   target="_blank" ><img  src ="t.png"   /> </a>    <img src="h.gif"  /><a id="yt" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAJxACKSdMM;autoplay=1" target="_blank"><img src ="t.png" /> </a> ....... When i Click on the particular image the light box must appear and the video must play from the youtube

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/#&togetherjs=U4OVR4n6Ql   there i have not included the fancybox plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-

1.3.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-

1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".yt").click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'padding'        : 0,
                        'autoScale'      : false,
                        'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                        'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                        'title'          : this.title,
                        'width'          : 680,
                        'height'         : 495,
                        'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                        'type'           : 'swf',
                        'swf'            : {
                            'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                            'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

        <h1>fancybox example</h1>
        <p><a class="yt" title="" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?
v=h3GEQIbcfwA&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">Movie1</a></p>
<p><a class="yt"  title="" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAJxACKSdMM">Movie2</a></p>



</body>
</html>
```

I have replaced `$(".yt")` in the jquery i.e  instead of `$("#yt")`, so it becomes `$(".yt").click(function()` and in the body of the HTML `class="yt"` has been added  instead of `id="yt"` in the `<a>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 elements in the HTML with the same ID. Use classes instead of IDs:

```
<a class="yt" href="..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

Then you can change the jQuery selector from `$("#yt")` to `$(".yt")` to bind the click event to all of the hyperlinks that have the `yt` class on them.

Comment: If you put the $(".yt") in the JQuery, lightbox won't appear it will redirected to youtube page. I want the lightbox to appear and the video to played from that link in lightbox.

Comment: You have to add `class="yt"` to each of the `<a>` elements that you want to open the YouTube videos.

Comment: If u change from "id" to "class" in the **<a>** also means it is redirecting the page but the LIGHTBOX is not appearing @Nerdwod

Comment: Can you show us the actual web page? It's very hard to guess at what is going on. If you can't show the actual page, can you put together a JSFiddle?

Comment: how to put the pulgin in the JSFiddle?

Comment: You might need to open the code on your own machine though

Comment: Does that code work for you? It's just using classes of "yt". You might need to use "http://" instead of "https://" for the YouTube URLs.

Comment: ya it worked for me. I have posted the answer. See it once.

Comment: That's not a new answer - it's just implementing exactly what I said to do in my answer. I think you should remove the big answer (as it is harder to read) and accept the answer as being correct.

Comment: `$("#yt , .yt").click(function()` This one. and   ` <a class="yt" class="yt" title="" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?
v=h3GEQIbcfwA&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1">sadf</a>`

Comment: The jQuery selector only needs to be `$(".yt")`, and the hyperlink should only have `class="yt"` once, not twice.